# netty 3.5.7 Channel.close() throws exception cause closefuture not notified

Tags: java, netty

I'm digging a bug in my netty program:I used a heartbeat handler between the server and client,when client system rebooting,the heartbeat handler in server side will be aware of timeout and then close the Channel,but sometimes the listener registered in Channel's CloseFuture never be notified,that's weird.

After digging netty 3.5.7 source code,I figure out that the only way a Channel's CloseFuture be notified is through AbstractChannel.setClosed();May be this method not be executed when Channel is closed,see below:

NioServerSocketPipelineSink:

```
private static void close(NioServerSocketChannel channel, ChannelFuture future) {
    boolean bound = channel.isBound();
    try {
        if (channel.socket.isOpen()) {
            channel.socket.close();
            Selector selector = channel.selector;
            if (selector != null) {
                selector.wakeup();
            }
        }

        // Make sure the boss thread is not running so that that the future
        // is notified after a new connection cannot be accepted anymore.
        // See NETTY-256 for more information.
        channel.shutdownLock.lock();
        try {
            if (channel.setClosed()) {
                future.setSuccess();
                if (bound) {
                    fireChannelUnbound(channel);
                }
                fireChannelClosed(channel);
            } else {
                future.setSuccess();
            }
        } finally {
            channel.shutdownLock.unlock();
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        future.setFailure(t);
        fireExceptionCaught(channel, t);
    }
}
```

in some platform channel.socket.close() may throw IOException,that means channel.setClosed() may never executed,so the listener registered in CloseFuture may not be notified.

Here is my question:Do you ever encounter this problem? Is the analysis right?

I figure out it's my heartbeat handler cause the problem:never timeout,so never close the channel,below is running in a timer :

```
if ((now - lastReadTime > heartbeatTimeout)
                    && (now - lastWriteTime > heartbeatTimeout)) {
                getChannel().close();
                stopHeartbeatTimer();
            }
```

where lastReadTime and lastWriteTime are updated like below:

```
public void writeComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WriteCompletionEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    lastWriteTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.writeComplete(ctx, e);
}

public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    lastReadTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.messageReceived(ctx, e);
}
```

Remote client is Windows xp,current server is Linux,both jdk1.6.
I think the writeComplete still invoked internally after remote client's system is rebooting,although messageReceived not invoked,no IOExceptoin is thrown during this period.

I will redesign the heartbeat handler,attaching a timestamp and a HEART_BEAT flag in heartbeat packet,when the peer side received the packet,send back the packet with the same timestamp and a ACK_HEART_BEAT flag,when the current side received this ack packet,use this timestamp to update lastWriteTime.

Comment: Maybe i can close the channel again in the heartbeat handler's exceptionCaught method.

Comment: Could please upgrade to 3.5.12.Final and let us know if the problem still exists?

Comment: 3.5.12 not solve this problem,but It seems the heartbeat handler cause the problem.